# How to authorize URL shorten request using Google URL Shortener API for Java

Tags: java, google-api-java-client, google-url-shortener

I'm developing GAE application that needs to send authorized shorten URL requests, so they show up in users http://goo.gl dashboard. I'm using Google URL shortener API for Java library (google-api-services-urlshortener-v1-rev12-1.12.0-beta.jar) following way:

```
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws IOException {

    Urlshortener shortener = newUrlshortener();
    Url toInsert = new Url().setLongUrl("http://www.google.com");
    Url inserted = new Url();
    try {
         inserted = shortener.url().insert(toInsert).setOauthToken("{accessToken}").execute();
      } catch (Exception e) {
     resp.sendError(404, e.getMessage());
      }

  }

public static Urlshortener newUrlshortener() {
    AppIdentityCredential credential =
        new AppIdentityCredential(Arrays.asList(UrlshortenerScopes.URLSHORTENER));
    return new Urlshortener.Builder(new UrlFetchTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential)
        .build();
  }
```

My request gets processed and I can retrieve short URL, but it does not show up in users http://goo.le dashboard.

I can do it using curl, and it works as it should. Request shows up in users dashboard:

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer {sameAccessToken}'  -d '{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}'
```

I have also tried adding Authorization HttpHeader to request but it didn't work:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer {sameAccessToken}");
        inserted = shortener.url().insert(toInsert).setRequestHeaders(headers).execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing it wrong way all the time.

Right way is to create Credential object and set Access token using setAccessToken() method.

```
public static Urlshortener newUrlshortener() {

    Credential credential = new Credential();
    credential.setAccessToken("{accessToken}");
    return new Urlshortener.Builder(new UrlFetchTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential)
    .build();

}
```